# How to check if something has been defined in the CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: c++, cmake

I've got something like this in the CMakeLists file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wextra -DFLAG")
```

Later **in the same CMakeLists.txt file**, I need to check if `FLAG` has been defined. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
IF(FLAG)
    target_link_libraries(${PRODUCT} ${LIBS1}) 
ELSE()
    target_link_libraries(${PRODUCT} ${LIBS2}) 
ENDIF()
```

I am also gonna check if `FLAG` has been defined in my c++ code. If defined, I will use codes from `LIBS1`, else I will make use of codes defined in `LIBS2` library set.

```
#ifdef FLAG
  // some code that uses LIBS1 libraries 
#else
  // some code that uses LIBS2 libraries  
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of a direct way but you can use string matches to get the flag:

```
STRING(REGEX MATCH "FLAG" result ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
IF(${result} MATCHES "FLAG"))
    #Add your code
ENDIF()
```